# change of pointer address unexpected during comparson

Tags: c, pointers

I was implementing a priority queue and trying to check the priority with the following code but this goes wrong unfortunately.

```
int i = 0;
int checker =-1;
printf("inserted priority:%d\n", *job.priority);
if(*job.priority == checker){//first arrival
    printf("priority of first arrival:%d\n",QueueNum);
    *job.priority = QueueNum;
}
else{
    printf("why are u running\n");
    printf("wtf priority:%d\n", *job.priority);
}
```

I use `printf()` to keep tracking the change in value and the result is shown

```
inserted priority:-1
why are u running
wtf priority:-1218044757
```

I don't understand what causes the change? How can i fix that?

Comment: This is the real code?

Comment: After `printf("inserted priority:%d\n", *job.priority);` add `printf("checker: %d\n", checker);` and `printf("==: %d\n", *job.priority == checker);`.

Comment: yes It is , the result is now 

"inserted priority:-1
checker: -1
==: 0
why are u running
wtf priority:-1218569045"

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I do a double check by inserting `printf("double check:%d \n", *job.priority);` after `printf("inserted priority:%d \n", *job.priority);` , and find that `*job.priority` already change. The result is like that now `inserted priority:-1 double check:-1080636936 
why are u running`

Comment: ok i fix it , the problem is the way i store value into priority,
originally i store it this way `int preset = -1;    list[pcount].priority = preset;`
  I didn't malloc to give priority memory space before.  
So I adjust in this way
`   int preset = -1;
   list[pcount].priority = (int*)mallooc(sizeof(int));
   *(list[pcount].priority) = -
`
Although i still don't understand why it first show'-1' then change its value, it now work correctly,